# User agent stylesheet overriding border styles

Tags: css, styles, overriding, user-agent

First off, let me say I am pretty new to coding in general, so please be specific in your responses =)
I am having an issue with borders around images on a site I am working on. You can see the site here: http://eventswithvizability.ca/

I have 10 images rotating on page reload, you can see the HTML here:

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
    function banner() { } ; b = new banner() ; n = 0
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter1'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg   CLASS='aligncenter2'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg   CLASS='aligncenter3'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg   CLASS='aligncenter4'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg   CLASS='aligncenter5'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg   CLASS='aligncenter6'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter7'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg   CLASS='aligncenter8'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg   CLASS='aligncenter9'>"
    b[n++]= "<IMG name=randimg  CLASS='aligncenter10'>"
    i=Math.floor(Math.random() * n) ; 
    document.write( b[i] )
    </SCRIPT>
```

Basically I want no borders around my images. I have firebug installed, and I can see when inspecting the element that is is reading my style for the images (so no borders), but nothing I do is changing the fact that I still have a border displaying around my images.

```
    media="all"
    img[class*="align"], img[class*="wp-image-"] {
    margin: auto;
    border: none !important;
    border-style: none !important;
    border-width: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-color: transparent !important; 
    /*test to see if I can get rid of bottom border*/
    }
```

I have tried fixing my doctype, adding a reset stylesheet, adding !important all over the place, and reading everything I could track down on google, but it is still picking up this **border-style:initial;** script from somewhere. If it is the browser, then my reset stylesheet should have taken care of it..right?

Please help! I am going batty trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

This is a bug in the rendering engine, which you're triggering by trying to give an `img` tag a transparent .PNG as a background and then re-scaling it.  You can fix this by either:

1. Changing your `img` tags to `div` tags - then the browser doesn't have so much trouble giving them backgrounds.
2. Rather than setting the background property of the `img` tags, set their `src` to the image URLs instead.

**Long answer**

The border is not being created with CSS; you can tell this because if you add a border property like `border:1px solid black` the new border will coexist with the one causing you trouble.  By the same token, `border-style:initial` is not at fault; that's just a side-effect of your stating `border-none` (`initial` just means that the element should take the default value for the attribute).

The technical cause has to do with bugs in browser rendering engines when re-scaling transparent .PNGs.  Some examples of similar bugs being noticed elsewhere are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538082/firefoxs-renders-thin-grey-lines-at-content-box-edges-of-a-png-at-certain-widths) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=490997).

But in your case, the proximate cause of the issue seems to be the somewhat unorthodox method being used to display the images, specifically the use of transparent .PNGs as the background (rather than the source) of your `img` tags.  This would be bad practice, even if it weren't the case that in the process of stretching the transparent .PNGs to fill the background of the `img`, the rendering engine is creating the grey artifacts that look like borders.

If you want to implement the second option in Javascript, the following should do the trick:

```
<script language="javascript">
    i= Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 9);
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i
    }
    document.write('<img src="http://eventswithvizability.ca/wp-content/themes/lugada/images/bottom' + i + '.png" class="random_image" id="random_image_' + i + '" alt="" />')
</script>
```

Note that rather than going to the trouble of creating an array with the code for each image stored separately, you can just generate the random variables and then use string concatenation to patch together an `img` tag on the fly.

Also, you'll save yourself trouble generally if instead of having 10 custom CSS classes for each image, all with the same content, you instead have one class applied to them all.  Remember, `id` attributes must be unique, but not classes.

Comment: OMFG you are my hero! That code totally worked to clear up the issue in Chrome.
However, nothing is displaying in IE. Is this because of the "unorthodox" methods I used? (Thanks for not saying I am super dumb). If so how would I fix this issue? I have already taken your advice and removed all the image classes replacing it with one class.

Comment: Glad to help!  The image is displaying for me, on IE9 / Windows 7.  What version of IE and what operating system is it not displaying on?

Comment: Also, continuing errors may be the result of some problems with the code which you can see on the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Feventswithvizability.ca%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  You can use this tool to check if there are obvious (and sometimes not-so-obvious) problems.