# Chrome User Agent Stylesheet table border-color not overridden

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table

I have a table that's markup resembles this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Label</th>
    <td>Data</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Label</th>
    <td>Data</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have CSS making borders on the `th`, `td` with shorthand border declaration. On the first `th` my top and left border color is getting overridden by the border-color on the Chrome User Agent Stylesheet. See the image below:

[image: Where it's overriding my styles, this is showing styles for the th]

To fix this issue I have tested and tried the following:

1. Confirmed that the doctype is there `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. Added table, tr, th, td { border-color: #fff; } to attempt to override the style
3. Changed the first `th` to a `td`, which removed the `background-color`, and fixed the issue. Until I added the `background-color` back to the `td`, which broke it again.
4. Removed the background color from all `th`'s, which fixed the issue, but won't work for the design.
5. Isolated the `th` in question with a class and tried to override border-color with important. It did not work, because the border color it's using is coming from table, not the th or td.

I am looking for possibly directions I'm missing to fix this issue, I cannot share more detailed code due to the nature of the work I do (government applications), but I can provide more detail if needed

Comment: We don't need to see your data, but at least some css. And a fiddle reproducing the issue would be even better... Seems to work just fine, as one would expect: http://jsfiddle.net/6k6dx7b6/

Comment: I can't reproduce it in fiddle. That's why I'm not asking for a solution, more if other people have seen this same type issue, so I can dig in another direction.

Comment: I'm still not sure what this bug was, but it has been fixed by removing the border-collapse: collapse; that my predecessor had used.

Comment: this proplem happens only in high resolution screens any idea to remove that style

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
table *{
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Changing img to div solved my problem.
Look here [User agent stylesheet overriding border styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163448/user-agent-stylesheet-overriding-border-styles)